# Как заставить request правильно получить html

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, grab

Уже второй день не могу сделать простенький запрос на сайт. 
Запрос должен получить html, а он выдает '�SE�l�' c options.gzip=false, а с true ' '
Сам npm модуль: github.com/request/request
Вот код:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var options = {
        url:'https://csgosell.com/phpLoaders/getInventory/getInventory.php',
        encoding : 'utf8',
        gzip : true,
        forever: true,
        headers: {
   'Host': 'csgosell.com',
   'Connection': 'keep-alive',
   'Content-Length': '58',
   'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
   'Accept': '*/*',
   'Origin': 'https://csgosell.com',
   'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36',
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
   'Referer': 'https://csgosell.com/',
   'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
   'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
   'Cookie': 'my-cookies from browser'

        
        },
        form: {
            stage:'bot',
            steamId:76561198284997423,
            hasBonus:false,
            coins:0
        }
    };



    request.post(options, 
        function(error, response, body){
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            if (!error) {
                fs.writeFileSync('csgosell.html', body);
            }
            else{
              console.log(error);
            }
         }
    );
```

Вот запрос chrome [image: запрос из chrome]

А вот мой запрос из node.js [image: Запрос из nodejs]

Заголовки отличаются лишь 
:authority:csgosell.com :method:POST :path:/phpLoaders/getInventory/getInventory.php :scheme:https

Погуглив, я понял  это http2, попытался поставить request другого агента но ничего не изменилось.

```js
var spdy = require('spdy');

var agent = spdy.createAgent({
  host: 'csgosell.com',
  port: 443,
  spdy: {
    ssl: true,
  }


}).once('error', function (err) {
  this.emit(err);
});

//и соответственно
options.agent = agent;
```